# Changing numbers of decimals

Tags: ruby, floating-point, constants

I made a little script that gives the number PI with x decimals. 
I use the Salamin-Brent algorithm to find PI and I don't want to use Math::PI.
The problem is that the result is always with 15 decimals.

I found the `Float::DIG` constant that I redefine, but nothing change (even when I decrease it).

Here is how I redefine it :

```
puts Float::DIG         #=> 15
Float::DIG = 2
puts Float::DIG         #=> 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aside from oldergod's original answer of using string manipulation

```
'%0.4f' % Math::PI # "3.1416"
```

you can also use `round`

```
Math::PI.round(4) # 3.1416
```

`4` in both examples determine the number of decimal places you want.  The main difference between the two is the first one returns a string and the second one a float.  I prefer the second one because it's easier to read.

Comment: It's a good solution, but in my case I don't want to use Math::PI. I use the Salamin-Brent algorithm to find PI.

Comment: no, it's just an example. change `Math::PI` to a different variable or even the value itself like `3.1415678.round(4)`